# Remove duplicate data in multidimension array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I want to remove duplicate data in my array.

That's my array :

```
$monTableau = array (
  array("pomme","noix de coco","pêche"),
  array("fraise","pomme", "framboise"),
  array("ananas","citron","raisin"),
  array("pêche","pruneau","pomme")
);
```

My multidimensionnal array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => pomme
            [1] => noix de coco
            [2] => pêche
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => fraise
            [1] => pomme
            [2] => framboise
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => ananas
            [1] => citron
            [2] => raisin
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => pêche
            [1] => pruneau
            [2] => pomme
        )

)
```

and that's my code to try remove duplicate data:

```
 $monTableau = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $monTableau)));
```

Don't work unfortunately :(

Advance Thanks,

Comment: Can you post an array we can work with? Maybe the unserialiezd one

Comment: Sorry, yes of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does work properly, but there is no duplicates in the main array. If you want one single array as output that contains only unique elements of the whole list take a look at this code:

```
$monTableau = array (
  array("pomme","noix de coco","pêche"),
  array("fraise","pomme", "framboise"),
  array("ananas","citron","raisin"),
  array("pêche","pruneau","pomme")
);


$merged = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $monTableau);
$unique = array_unique($merged);
```

Output of `$unique`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => pomme
    [1] => noix de coco
    [2] => pêche
    [3] => fraise
    [5] => framboise
    [6] => ananas
    [7] => citron
    [8] => raisin
    [10] => pruneau
)
```

Duplicates of `pomme` have been removed